# 401 Response using Google Cloud API in Android App

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to use Google AppEngine with my app (to replace AWS).  I have the datastore working with the following code:

```
themeendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new themeendpoint.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new JacksonFactory(),
            new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
            });

    themeendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
            endpointBuilder).build();
    DbAdapter dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(mCtx);
    try {
        CollectionResponseTheme response = endpoint.listTheme().execute();        
        List<Theme> listResponse = response.getItems();
...
```

However, when I try to use the following code for the Cloud Storage API (added using Eclipse-->Google-->Add Google APIs) to download a zip file that I have stored:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + mLocalPath + mZipName);

    Builder storageBuilder = new Storage.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new JacksonFactory(),
            new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
            });

    Storage storage = storageBuilder.build();


    Storage.Objects.Get get = storage.objects().get(GAE_WEBDATA.PUBLIC_ZIP_BUCKET, mZipName);

    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        get.executeAndDownloadTo(stream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"location" : "Authorization",
"locationType" : "header",
"message" : "Login Required",
"reason" : "required"
 } ],
  "message" : "Login Required"
}
```

In cloud console I have Google Cloud Storage set to 'On'.  The particular bucket permissions are set to 'All Users' = 'Reader'. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to read an object, bucket permissions aren't necessary. Instead, you need to set the OBJECT permissions to public-read.

You can fix the object permissions via the cloud console or from the command line via gsutil. The command is:

```
gsutil acl set public-read gs://bucketName/objectName
```

Comment: What if I don't want it to be public? I only want my app to be able to download it.

Comment: That's a surprisingly deep question. Can any anonymous users download and install your app? Do they need to set up some sort of account in order to be permitted to download the object? If you have some way of authenticating trusted users, handing signed URLs to those users is the canonical way to address the problem.

Comment: Theoretically no anonymous users can since download it since it is only in Google play and everyone would have a gumshoe account. I dont want to use oauth2 though since that requires a user's permission from a pop-up (as I understand it)